# AttributeError: module 'boto3' has no attribute 'client'

Tags: boto3

I have run into the above issue when running a script with the following usage of boto3:

`client = boto3.client('ses', region_name=AWS_REGION)`

The following package version has been installed:
`boto3 (1.12.36)`

Would really appreciate some help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you name the current script or any file as `boto3.py`?

Comment: Add your code for better response.